# Rails dev server hanging on request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using `ubuntu 14.04LTS`, `react-rails 1.0.0`, `rails 4.2.1`, and `ruby 2.2.2`.

I'm booting up the rails server with `bin/rails s`.  I make an edits and refresh my page on the browser.  Whenever I do this 2 times, my third edit/refresh gets me this in the terminal:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-23 10:10:29 -0700
```

and then my computer's cpu starts spinning and I never move on and I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> out of the server.

The first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> hangs and I get

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-23 10:32:24 -0700
^C[2015-04-23 10:32:28] INFO  going to shutdown ...
```

so if I do another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I get

```
^C[2015-04-23 10:28:54] INFO  going to shutdown ...
^CExiting
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:49:in `shutdown': undefined method `shutdown' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

What is wrong with my server?

Comment: Have you tried using gdb to dump stack traces from the process?

Comment: Does this happen with other versions of Ruby?

Comment: @ChrisHeald how would I do that?

Comment: @tadman also had the same error with `ruby 2.2.0`

Comment: https://blog.newrelic.com/2013/04/29/debugging-stuck-ruby-processes-what-to-do-before-you-kill-9/

Comment: A possibility is asset compilation process that eats quite some CPU. However, this is only relevant to large projects with a lot of assets and a large changeset imported from the repository at once. I've never seen this process last more than 5 minutes, so.. maybe just wait that long. Then panic :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe possible that the binary that you're using for rails isn't what you think it is?  Make sure that its the version you want to be using.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. It was caused by DNS issues with the mysql host.
If you're using an external mysql host, make sure you can reach your DNS server and it properly resolves the name to the mysql IP.

In my case, it tried to send DNS queries to the wrong server - which didn't respond - causing rails to hang for a long time.